# Set checkbox background transparent

Tags: vba, excel

I can't for the life of me find how to set a form control checkbox background to transparent

```
Dim cb As CheckBox

For Each cb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    cb.Value = -4146
    cb.Interior.Color = ???
Next cb
```

To be clear I'm talking about a Forms checkbox on a worksheet, not on a form and not an ActiveX checkbox (Developer menu > Insert > Form Controls).

I recorded a macro and got this but I'm wondering if there's a way to do it via the Checkbox object rather than use the Shape object. Even a link to the MSDN Dev page for a Form Controls checkbox would help as I can't find it!

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("cb1_1").Fill.Visible = msoFalse
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cb.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
```